# Duvida de como recuperar dados de outra tabela com Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Possuo duas tabelas: Departamento com id e nome

Telefone contem id_departamento e ramal

Ja cadastrei um departamento e alguns ramais em que o id_departamento faz referencia ao departamento cadastrado

Em PostGres, como seria o select pra eu buscar todos os ramais referentes ao Departamento que cadastrei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select t.ramal from Telefone t 
    join Departamento d on d.id = t.id_departamento
where d.id = {id que vc quer}
```

obs: como id_departamento é uma foreign key eu trocaria o nome para fk_departamento

Comment: Obrigado Arthur, funcionou certinho. Abraço